# custom hook returning functions in typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting a typescript error on a custom hook.
My hook returns 3 functions. Two with no arguments and one with a function argument.
When I use the hook and call the first function typescript causes an error saying the function needs an argument when the function its calling doesn't have an argument. It seems to be looking for the argument that the last function in the array is looking for ?

```
const useHook = () => {

  const onResult = (listener: (result: any) => void) => {
    return API.onResult((content) => {
      listener(content.access);
    });
  };

  const start = () => {
    console.log("start>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  };

  const stop = () => {
    console.log("stop >>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  };

  return [start, stop, onResult];
};

export default useHook;
```

Using the hook is causing an error

```
 const [startSystem, stopSystem, onResult] = useHook();
 startSystem();
```

Typescript error on startSystem()

> const startSystem: (listener: (result: any) => void) => void Expected
> 1 arguments, but got 0 useHook.ts An argument for 'listener' was not
> provided.

Why would it be asking for the argument that is needed in onResult in both startSystem and stopSystem ?
Neither of those two have arguments.

Comment: This is due to the type inference from Typescript, as you haven't typed your tuple it's assuming its not a tuple but an array that has elements of type `typeof start | typeof stop | typeof onResult` to fix this this type your tuple. i.e. `const useHook = (): [() => void, () => void, (listener: (result: any) => void) => any] => { /* rest of code */};`

Comment: Could I write this with an interface, I tried at the top of the hook adding my interface and then assigning it like this. const useHook = (): IHook[] => { } but this didn;t work. My Ihook has my function declarations.

Comment: `IHook[]` is still an array. if you want to individually identify each index of the array (using it as a tuple) you will need to type it in the form `[ IStartFn, IStopFn, IOnResultFn ]`. you should be able to assign it to a type i.e. `type HookReturn = [ IStartFn, IStopFn, IOnResultFn ];` and then using it `cont useHook = (): HookReturn => {};`.